# Launching Kinect on PR2 Gazebo to get same topics like openni_launch?

Tags: gazebo, kinect, turtlebot, gazebo-plugins, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Information has been updated, but this documentation doesn't mention Gazebo: 
http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera 
http://ros.org/wiki/openni_launch

To test a real OpenNI device, I can run:

```
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

which will produce all the topics listed below.

If you launch a PR2 or Turtlebot in Gazebo simulation, it only outputs the raw data. So there are no topics like:

> /camera/rgb/image_color

What's the best way to launch image_proc & depth_image_proc nodelets?

Will this work?

```
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch load_driver:=false depth_registration:=true
```

(I can't test anything at the moment)

Are there any plans to include this with the PR2 or Turtlebot simulators? 
(*turtlebot_bringup/launch/3dsensor.launch* gave me some ideas, but I guess it's only for the real robot)

Thanks, 
David.

**Topics published from real OpenNI device:**

```
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/disparity
/camera/depth/image
/camera/depth/image/compressed
/camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth
/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image/theora
/camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect/theora
/camera/depth/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressed
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/theora
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/points
/camera/depth/rectify_depth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/rectify_depth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/camera_info
/camera/depth_registered/disparity
/camera/depth_registered/image
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image/theora
/camera/depth_registered/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/compressed
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/theora
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/compressed
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/theora
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth_registered/points
/camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/parameter_updates
/camera/driver/parameter_descriptions
/camera/driver/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/camera_info
/camera/ir/image_raw
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressed
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_raw/theora
/camera/ir/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_rect
/camera/ir/image_rect/compressed
/camera/ir/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/ir/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_rect/theora
/camera/ir/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/rectify_ir/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/rectify_ir/parameter_updates
/camera/projector/camera_info
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/debayer/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/debayer/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_color
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_mono
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora
/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect
/camera/rgb/image_rect/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect/theora
/camera/rgb/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/theora
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/rectify_color/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/rectify_color/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/rectify_mono/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/rectify_mono/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52045/launching-kinect-on-pr2-gazebo-to-get-same-topics-like-openni_launch?/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Almost; you'll also want to set the camera name argument to "head_mount_kinect", since that is what the pr2 typically uses:

roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch load_driver:=false depth_registration:=true camera:=head_mount_kinect

EDIT: That's if you're running the pr2 in gazebo. I'm not sure what camera name the turtlebot uses.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-01-15**:
Thanks @jbinney   .  I also had to make a copy of the launch file and add an argument to disable the two nodelets that generate PointClouds, because the Gazebo plugin generates the PointClouds directly.

**Comment by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) on 2014-08-25**:
hi, i am working towards the same thing but i want to use turtlebot so i am wondering what the camera name should be in this case?

**Comment by [tiberium24](https://answers.ros.org/users/36069/tiberium24/) on 2018-06-24**:
I am trying the same thing and getting
rostopic echo camera/depth_registered/image_raw
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?

How to resolve this??